# Random print before login after restarting in Ubuntu from Windows on a dual-boot

Tags: 22.04, printing, authentication

It does not make too much sense, but this just happened.

As the title says I have a dual-boot, Windows 10 - Ubuntu 22 laptop. I have restarted the system (actually switched the operating system from Windows to Ubuntu) and when it got to the login screen in Ubuntu, my printer started printing one of the documents on my Ubuntu desktop. This, while on the login screen, before authentication, without me touching anything.

Incidentally, the document was a saved chat I had with my bank, so you can imagine why this is highly concerning.

Can someone please explain how is this possible? How could I figure out why it happened, so I can look for a solution to make sure it will not repeat?

Before logging in I switched to a terminal view, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to get a terminal and authenticated. Then I ran `who` and only my user was showed as being logged in.

Is it possible that this was a print job that was not completed in the past (although I don't remember ever attempting to print this document), due to the printer being off and it only printed now since the printer was available? This is a wild guess, since a few minutes earlier I was in the exact same context, but it did not print anything. If this could be the issue, is it expected to print without me being logged in?

**Edit:**

- The printed document was only available to Ubuntu.
- The printer was just powered on a few minutes before (while in Windows), after about a month of inactivity.

Comment: Probably a buffer in the printer being flushed on initialization. You printed the document (or Windows did for you), and turned it off before the print was printed

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the details. I don't know much about printers and how their buffer is flushed, but it was turned off for a long time, and since it was turned back on I have never logged into Ubuntu. The printed document was only available to Ubuntu.